# Не могу получить token. Sprin Security

Tags: spring, безопасность, spring-security

Добрый день.
Настроил Spring Security:

```
@Configuration
public class ProjectSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

private DataSource dataSource;

public ProjectSecurity(DataSource dtiDataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dtiDataSource;
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/ping").permitAll().anyRequest()
            .fullyAuthenticated()
            .and()
              .formLogin().loginPage("/login") 
              .usernameParameter("username")
              .passwordParameter("password")
            .and()
              .logout().permitAll();
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(this.dataSource)
    .usersByUsernameQuery(
        "userRead.security_pkg.getUser(?)")
    .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(
        "select username, role from user_roles where username=?");

}
```

}

Пытаюсь получить token, отправляю запрос:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"username":"steve","password":"steve"}' http://localhost:8080/login/
```

Такие юзер и пароль есть в базе.

В базе пытаюсь обратиться к хранимой функции. Не понимаю как это сделать. Выпадает ошибка:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index
```

Comment: csrf это защита от кроссдоменных запросов, вам сначала нужно получить этот токен, только после этого вы сможете делать другие запросы, такие как post и т.п.

Comment: А как получить-то его?
Отключить защиту?
@Komdosh

Comment: Тут есть ответ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19827164/how-can-i-get-a-csrf-token-from-the-command-line

Comment: Там предлагают включить в запрос, заранее полученый token. Мне это не подходит. Мне надо отправить логин и пароль и получить token

Comment: Эм, читайте, что написано выше, вы не сможете залогиниться, пока не получите csrf токен, вам нужно сначала его получить, а потом уже логиниться

Comment: Я отключиле его путем http.csrf().disable(). Теперь ошибка {"timestamp":1508934382868,"status":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"Access Denied","path":"/login/"}

Comment: ну да, теперь вы обращаетесь к странице, к которой требуется login :), скорее всего нужно разрешить заходить на неё без логина

Comment: ))) Дак как мне token получить?)

Comment: `.fullyAuthenticated()` можете его убрать? Вот где-то там собака зарыта :)

Comment: Пока не убирал. В консоли выпадает ошибка: bad SQL grammar [select username,password, enabled from users where username=?]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist. Не пойму пока почему

Comment: Такое чувство, что запрос не правильный....